# CORS PHP File Upload

Tags: javascript, php, cors

I'm performing a CORS file upload using PHP.

However, a few things confuse me.

I'm using FormData in Javascript. I also use `encodeURIComponent`. However, when I send the request, `$_POST is empty`. `$_FILES` is also empy.

However when I check this...

`php://input`

The submitted fields are there. The file I submitted is also there.

I am confused because `php://input` should not be available with `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

I set the content type of the `XDomainRequest` to `"multipart/form-data"`

What is happenening?

```
var_dump($_POST); 
var_dump($_FILES); 
var_dump(file_get_contents(''php://input''));
```

Comment: can you show us what your code look like?

Comment: Here is the JS = https://jsfiddle.net/v95k7cyy/

Comment: @Mubashar Here is the PHP = 

var_dump($_POST); var_dump($_FILES); var_dump(file_get_contents(''php://input''));

Comment: Here is typo of ' in jsfiddle it should be
var url = '/upload_document';

Comment: Okay, typo fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found my mistake.

`request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data");`

I'm not supposed to do that, because that will leave the form content separator blank. Because the content separator is blank, PHP can't read the post body properly.